# Django DetailView but get_object_or_404() instead of get_object()

Tags: django

I have Django Model that has a `live` boolean attribute.

I want the View to get the Model by slug and only go to this page if it's live USING THE DetailView (not function based view, because I want to see how to do it.

Model definition

```
# myapp/models.py

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    live = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
```

I hoped it would be done something like this:

```
class ModelDetailView(DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        service = self.get_object_or_404(Service, live=True)  # <- Main point of what I'm looking for help with
        return super().get(request, *args, *kwargs)
```

Is there a way to filter this way?

Comment: A class-based view has *no* `get_object_or_404`, the `get_object` however will raise a `Http404` exception.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is there a  way to filter in get_object()? Like "get_object(live=True)" or something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the `queryset` to filter, so:

```
class ModelDetailView(DetailView):
    model = MyModel
    queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(live=True)
```

You thus do not need to implement the `.get(…)` method at all.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: Where can one find this in the official docs? I certainly couldn't find it on the [QuerySet API page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/)!

Comment: The filtering itself is in the [*QuerySet* API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/), the details about the view are in the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview

Comment: Thank you. My bad - I didn't realize `live=True` is a custom check. Just re-read the whole question carefully. I had seen that elsewhere in another tutorial and assumed it's a part of the framework, where it is just a convention. Thanks anyway and sorry for the bother! :)